# Status Indicators on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, kpi

I am looking to create some kind of status indicators for a list that I have produced. I just want a simple red, amber, green setup.

I came across the status indicator webpart but I couldn't get this to work with my list. I have had a look online and have read that this webpart has been discontinued in SharePoint Online (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-microsoft-sharepoint-2013-bbbb0815-2538-4f1d-b647-1f7f6d508c93?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)?!

Does anyone know if this is the case and if so how would I go about making a simple status indicator on my list on SharePoint Online?

Comment: Let me see if I get the idea, you want to set a column that depending on a value , show green, yellow or red?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. Like a basic traffic light system show green for complete, amber for in progress and red for not started. Is that what can be done in status indicators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office-365 introduced a Client Rendering Mode (CSR) which represents a rendering engine for list views, list forms and search results. I would recommend you to consider that approach. [Example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a) and [Article](https://threewill.com/client-side-rendering-sharepoint-2013/)

**CSR Example**
Assume you have **Priority** column in the list with (high, normal or low) values. Save following file as .js extension and upload to your style library and link to list webaprt JsLink property.

```
(function () {
    // Initialize the variable that stores the objects.
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};

    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
         'Priority': { 'View': priorityIndicatorFiledTemplate }
             };

    // Register the template overrides.
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

})();

function priorityIndicatorFiledTemplate(ctx) { 
var _ProrityText = ctx.CurrentItem.Priority;


switch (_ProrityText.toLowerCase()) { 
        case "high": 
            return "<span style='color :#f00'><img src='/Style%20Library/Images/Red.png' width='10px' height='10px' /> " + _ProrityText+ "</span>"; 
            break; 
        case "normal": 
            return "<span style='color :#ff6a00'><img src='/Style%20Library/Images/Green.png' width='13px' height='13px' /> " + _ProrityText+ "</span>"; 
            break; 
        case "low": 
            return "<span style='color :#cab023'><img src='/Style%20Library/Images/Orange.png' width='10px' height='10px' /> " + _ProrityText+ "</span>"; 
    } 
}
```

---

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: I'm new to Sharepoint and coding as well. I have a small question, with respect to the above code, how do I mention a column name if my Internal column name is different from my display column name? (Ex: In my custom list, the display column name is '2017_q1' and my internal column name is '_x0032_017_x0020_q1')

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSR (Client Side Rendering) technique. Create a .js file and add it as a JSLink to the webpart (View o Form).
Here an example for a field called `Status` in a list view:

```
(function () {

    var statusFieldContext = {};
    statusFieldContext.Templates = {};
    statusFieldContext.Templates.Fields = {
        "Status": { "View": statusFieldTemplate }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldContext);

})();

function statusFieldTemplate(ctx) {

    var status = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];

    switch (status) {
        case "Completed":
            return "<span style='color :#008000'>" + status + "</span>";
            break;
        case "In Progress":
            return "<span style='color :#FDF5E6'>" + status + "</span>";
            break;
        case "Not Started":
            return "<span style='color :#FF0000'>" + status + "</span>";
    }
}
```

[Here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a) you can take a look on other examples and how to add the jslink to the webpart.