# SharePoint Online: Status Indicator / Stop Lights

Tags: sharepoint-online, kpi

I have 3 columns:

- InorOut
- In (calculated field)
- Out (calculated field)

The In and Out columns displays the icon using this formula:

```
="<DIV style='text-align:center'>"&IF([In or Out]="In","<img src='/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-0.GIF' align='middle'>","")&"</DIV>"
```

I also set the return data type to number.  It was working for months until today. I took a screenshot yesterday so I know it was working:
[image]

Today, it displays the code instead of the icons. Any idea how to fix this or maybe another way to display status icons? I found and tried  [Status Indicators on SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/204802/status-indicators-on-sharepoint-online) but it didn't work or I wasn't doing it right.

Below is the js code I'm using:

```
(function() {
var oFldCtx = {};
oFldCtx.Templates = {};
oFldCtx.Templates.Fields = {"InorOut": {"View": overrideStatus} };
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(oFldCtx);
})();
function overrideStatus(ctx) {
var sStatus = ctx.CurrentItem.InorOut;
var sIconFileName = "";
switch(sStatus) {
    case "In":
            sIconFileName = "KPIDefault-0.GIF";
        break;
    case "Out":
            sIconFileName = "KPIDefault-2.GIF";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
if (sIconFileName == "") return sStatus;
var sWebURL = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
var sIconSrc = sWebUrl + "/_catalogs/masterpage/DS/icons/" + sIconFileName;
var sImgTag = "<img id='" + ctx.CurrentItem.ID + "' ";
sImgTag += "src='" + sIconSrc + "' ";
sImgTag += "/>";
return sImgTag;
}
```

**Resolution: Fixed the typo (WebURL vs. WebUrl) in the above code**

The js file is not loading (404), below is the js file properties -- did I set it incorrectly?
[image]

**Resolution: I learned more about the js properties by reading this [link](https://wonderlaura.com/2014/09/11/sharepoint-conditional-formatting/). The article also explained more about the usage of ~site and ~sitecollection in the JS Link I initially didn't understand**

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a new change to the calculated column from today as per [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032106/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields).

Using CSR (JS Link) we can achieve the same functionality. Below is a complete article to learn CSR.

[How to work with CSR on SharePoint List](http://www.aerieconsulting.com/blog/using-a-js-link-override-in-sharepoint-online)

Comment: Hi Venkat.  I followed and tweak it to my list.  The column name is "InorOut" but displays as "In or Out" with spaces.  After I added the js link (last step), the column still displays the text rather than the image.

Comment: Can you confirm the js files loading? Or add an alert statement before return statement like this `alert(sImgTag)`

Comment: I added the alert statement like you suggested and saved the js file. Reload the list page, no alerts.

Comment: it means your file is not loaded. Where this JS file has been located. If it is in site collection library path should be `~sitecollection/folder path/filename.js` or if it is in site library `~site/folder path/filename.js`

Comment: I added it here: /_catalogs/masterpage/DS/js/InOutIndicator.js

Comment: Ok. Can you verify once again is your JS file loading or not

Comment: What other ways to test if the js file is loading? I saved it again through SPD and reload the list page but nothing is happening. I left the alert statement. Sorry, this is my first attempt creating a js file.

Comment: add an alert statement as a first line in the JS just like this `alert('loaded')`. If you get alerted then JS file has been loaded

Comment: Thanks Venkat for all the help and walkthrough.  I'll try again tomorrow and post the result.

Comment: Hi Venkat, it is still not loading.  the path to the js file is `https://xxx.sharepoint.com/teams/ddd/_catalogs/masterpage/ds/js/inoutindicator.js`, on SharePoint, I added this link `ddd/_catalogs/masterpage/ds/js/inoutindicator.js` I also tried adding `teams` but it still not loading. The dev tools is displaying 404.  Any idea?  Thank you

Comment: Just update path to `/_catalogs/masterpage/ds/js/inoutindicator.js`

Comment: It still didn't work. I don't know where I went wrong.  In the dev tool, below is the response body `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>BlobNotFound</Code><Message>The specified blob does not exist.
RequestId:f858e266-0001-0031-1f2f-e58861000000
Time:2017-06-14T16:55:21.3478433Z</Message></Error>`

Comment: Can you move this file site collection style library folder `JS`. and refere the path like `~sitecollection/Style Library/JS/inoutindicator.js`

Comment: I uploaded the js file in the Style Library, checked it in, changed the jslink path to `/ddd/style library/js/inoutindicator.js` or `/style  library/js/inoutindicator.js` both path didn't work.  :(

Comment: I am mentioning path should be this in your case `~sitecollection/Style Library/JS/inoutindicator.js`

Comment: I actually tried that before and like I said first time adding a js link. I thought **~site** or **~sitecollection** meant to add the site/site collection name (i.e. DDD) in the JSLink. Also, my code had a typo I didn't catch yesterday.  WebURL vs. WebUrl, after I fixed the code, it is now working.  Thanks Venkat for being patience and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Some other JS Link references, posts, and templates that might be helpful: 
http://www.idubbs.com/blog/js-link-and-csr/

(start here) Hello World for JSLink
http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2014/js-link-hello-world/

Response to the change yesterday
http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2017/js-link-no-more-html-in-calculated-field-change/

Comment: Thanks Wes.  The links are quite helpful - I also found the pingback to [link](https://wonderlaura.com/2014/09/11/sharepoint-conditional-formatting/) excellent read.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I solved this issue:

1) Created the .js file in Notepad. I changed it from above code so that I could use the same js file in my subsites where the In/Out Board is being displayed/filtered by Department.

**InorOut** is my column name with In or Out value.

```
(function() {
var oFldCtx = {};
oFldCtx.Templates = {};
oFldCtx.Templates.Fields = {"InorOut": {"View": overrideStatus} };
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(oFldCtx);
})();

function overrideStatus(ctx) {
var sStatus = ctx.CurrentItem.InorOut;

if (sStatus == 'In')    {
    return "<img src='/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-0.GIF'/>";    }
if (sStatus == 'Out')   {
    return "<img src='/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-2.GIF'/>";    }
}
```

2) Uploaded and **checked-in** the js file in **Site Settings** > **Masterpages** > (I created a new folder called **DDD** and subfolder called **JS** (or `/_catalogs/masterpage/ddd/js/inoutindicator.js`)

3) After uploading the js file, I edited its properties to

- Content type: **JavaScript Display Template**
- Target Control Type: **View**
- Standalone: **Override**
- Target Scope: **/**
- Target List Template ID: **100**

4) Edited the web part displaying the in/out board and under **Miscellaneous** in web part properties, I entered the JS Link: `~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/ddd/js/inoutindicator.js`

This [link](https://wonderlaura.com/2014/09/11/sharepoint-conditional-formatting/) helped me understand that ~sitecollection or ~site really meant to enter this string of characters and how to understand the js file properties. :)

Again, thanks everyone for contributing and introducing me to CSR or JS Link.