# How to HIDE selected sharepoint list fields/Columns using Javascript or Jquery on VIEW page?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

**Please Help!**

I have a custom list with 3 columns, "Slno","Language","Status".Status is a choice field with choices "Ongoing" and "Terminated". The Color of the "Language" column changes based on the "status" column value.

[image]

CODE:

```
(function () {

    var StatusFieldContext = {}; 
    StatusFieldContext.Templates = {};
    StatusFieldContext.Templates.Fields = {
        "Language": {"View": ColorFiledTemplate}
    };   
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(StatusFieldContext);
})();
function ColorFiledTemplate(ctx) {

    var  lang = ctx.CurrentItem.Language;
    var  st = ctx.CurrentItem.Status; 

    switch (st) {
        case "Ongoing":
            return "<span style='background-color: #65FE18;display:block;width:200px;height:35px;'>" + lang + "</span>";           
            break;
        case "Terminated":
            return "<font style='background-color:#FF2402;display:block;width:200px;height:35px;'>"+ lang +"</font>";
            break;     
    }
}
```

Real Problem: I DO NOT want to display the field "Status". 
I tried modifying the view by not selecting the "Status"field. If I do so, nothing appears in the Language column.(Screenshot Attached).

[image]

**What do I do to display only "Slno" and "Language" field? How do I write the script?**

FYI: I'm using Script Editor to link the Javascript code to this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your rendering problem stems from the fact that in order to get a field's value on `ctx.CurrentItem` during rendering, you *must* include that column in the view.

However, in your case, you need values from a certain column, but don't want that column *seen* in the view.  So I think in your case, something like what Stan is suggesting will work, although I'd advise finding the column index dynamically, in case the field order changes in the view.  I would do that in a post-render function.

So in the part of your script where you are registering the override, I would add:

```
StatusFieldContext.OnPostRender = hideStatusColumn;
```

And then create another function:

```
function hideStatusColumn(ctx) {
    var positionOfStatusColumn = 0;
    // get all the headers
    var headers = document.querySelectorAll('.ms-listviewtable th');
    // loop through the headers and find your column
    // based on matching the DISPLAY name
    var len = headers.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (headers[i].innerHTML.indexOf('Status') != -1) {
            // we found the Status column!
            // but because :nth-child is 1-based not zero-based, we need to add one
            positionOfStatusColumn = i + 1;
        }
    }

    // now that we know the position of the Status column, we can hide all the cells

    // only one header, so we can use querySelector
    document.querySelector('.ms-listviewtable th:nth-child(' + positionOfStatusColumn + ')').style.display = 'none';

    // have to get all the regular td cells, so we have to use querySelectorAll
    document.querySelectorAll('.ms-listviewtable td:nth-child(' + positionOfStatusColumn + ')').forEach(function (cell) {
        cell.style.display = 'none';
    });
}
```

---

In response to your comment, in order to hide multiple columns, you would have to just find the positions of those columns also as you are looping through the headers, based on their *full* display names.  Then just repeat the same code to set `display:none` on the other cells.  Here's an updated function as an example.  I have also added a check to make sure you actually found the column in the view before trying to hide it, so you don't accidentally hide something you don't want to touch:

```
function hideMultipleStatusColumns(ctx) {
    // initialize the variables as null so we can
    // check to make sure we found values later
    var positionOfStatus1Column = null;
    var positionOfStatus2Column = null;
    var positionOfStatus3Column = null;
    // get all the headers
    var headers = document.querySelectorAll('.ms-listviewtable th');
    // loop through the headers and find your columns
    // based on matching the DISPLAY name
    var len = headers.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (headers[i].innerHTML.indexOf('Status 1') != -1) {
            // we found the Status 1 column!
            // but because :nth-child is 1-based not zero-based, we need to add one
            positionOfStatus1Column = i + 1;
        }
        if (headers[i].innerHTML.indexOf('Status 2') != -1) {
            positionOfStatus2Column = i + 1;
        }
        if (headers[i].innerHTML.indexOf('Status 3') != -1) {
            positionOfStatus3Column = i + 1;
        }
    }

    // now that we know the positions of the Status columns, we can hide all the cells

    // make sure we found the column before trying to hide anything
    if (positionOfStatus1Column != null) {
        // only one header, so we can use querySelector
        document.querySelector('.ms-listviewtable th:nth-child(' + positionOfStatus1Column + ')').style.display = 'none';

        // have to get all the regular td cells, so we have to use querySelectorAll
        document.querySelectorAll('.ms-listviewtable td:nth-child(' + positionOfStatus1Column + ')').forEach(function (cell) {
            cell.style.display = 'none';
        });
    }
    if (positionOfStatus2Column != null) {
        document.querySelector('.ms-listviewtable th:nth-child(' + positionOfStatus2Column + ')').style.display = 'none';
        document.querySelectorAll('.ms-listviewtable td:nth-child(' + positionOfStatus2Column + ')').forEach(function (cell) {
            cell.style.display = 'none';
        });
    }
    if (positionOfStatus3Column != null) {
        document.querySelector('.ms-listviewtable th:nth-child(' + positionOfStatus3Column + ')').style.display = 'none';
        document.querySelectorAll('.ms-listviewtable td:nth-child(' + positionOfStatus3Column + ')').forEach(function (cell) {
            cell.style.display = 'none';
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Though, one small concern, what if the last child column is NOT the only one column I want to hide. What if I have 8 more status columns to hide ? Do I have to write it as a new question ?

Comment: No, I will update my answer later this evening to address hiding multiple columns.

Comment: @ParinitaHirehal updated my answer.

Comment: This works just fine.... :) Thank you much @DylanCristy

Answer (score 3):

to hide **one** column , in the below script will hide cloumn named `Status`

```
<script>
function hideColumn()
{ 
     var header = document.querySelectorAll("[displayname="Status"]")[0].parentNode;
    var index = [].slice.call(header.parentNode.children).indexOf(header) + 1;
    header.style.display = "none";
    for (var i = 0, cells = document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(" + index + ")"); i < cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i].style.display = "none";}

}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('hideColumn');
</script>
```

to hide **multiple** columns , use the below script 
replace `col1, col2,col3` , with your columns names

```
<script>
function hideColumns()
{ 
  ["col1", "col2","col3"].forEach(function(col) {
    var header = document.querySelectorAll("[displayname='"+ col +"']")[0].parentNode; //Recommend wrapping displayname value with an apostrophe ' to handle column names containing spaces.
    var index = [].slice.call(header.parentNode.children).indexOf(header) + 1;
    header.style.display = "none";
    for (var i = 0, cells = document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(" + index + ")"); i < cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i].style.display = "none";}
    });
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('hideColumns');
</script>
```

Comment: This approach will not help here.  The problem is that the OP is using the values of the "Status" column to do conditional formatting using CSR in a list view, therefore the "Status" column _must_ be included in the view, or you won't have access to the data.  However, OP does not actually want the "Status" column to be _seen_ in the view.

Comment: @DylanCristy  thanks for the clarification, i edited my answer to match with the mentioned case,

Comment: @Ahmed Saeed, I just tried it and it is working flawlessly. Thank you.

Comment: @ParinitaHirehal welcome, glad to help

Comment: THANK YOU!!! This worked well for me. I added 1 suggestion to wrap the displayname value with an apostrophe (') to handle column names containing spaces.

Comment: @A.Saéed Heavy dude!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should hide the column with javascript after changing the color. Best bet would be to select the tr and th based on their columns numeric value. Examples below:

```
$('table[summary="Shared Documents"] th')[1].hide();
$('table[summary="Shared Documents"] tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).children()[2].hide();
})
```